# How to do a effective Join when querying Huge table with small table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables consider TABLE A and TABLE B .TABLE A have 5 million records and TABLE B have 20 K records . I'm joining the large table with small table where I checking TABLE A record with table B record each by each.

```
DECLARE @Large TABLE (INN BIGINT,OUTT BIGINT )
INSERT INTO @Large (INN,OUTT)values (11356686,2101189)
INSERT INTO @Large (INN,OUTT)values (11369336,2101301)
INSERT INTO @Large (INN,OUTT)values (11358687,2101487)
INSERT INTO @Large (INN,OUTT)values (11369337,2101609)

DECLARE @small TABLE (INN BIGINT,OUTT BIGINT )
INSERT INTO @small (INN,OUTT)values (11356686,2101189)
INSERT INTO @small (INN,OUTT)values (11369337,2101609)
```

LARGE :

```
INN          OUTT
11356686    2101189
11369336    2101301
11358687    2101487
11369337    2101609
```

SMALL :

```
INN          OUTT
11356686    2101189
11369337    2101609
```

My query :

```
Select CASE WHEN T.INN IS NULL THEN O ELSE 1 END from  @LARGE T
LEFT JOIN @SMALLTT
ON T.INN = TT.INN AND T.OUTT = TT.OUTT
```

Coming to the tables they are well indexed and even no hints are there in Execution plan to add more indexes. 
Can any one suggest me what should I do in the query level to get results more quicker like CROSS APPLY,HASH JOIN etc.;

Comment: If you could [edit] your question so that the tables will be called `@small` and `@large` and add a link to [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) it could probably help.

Comment: Is there a problem here? The SQL Query Optimizer should figure out the best performance option on its own, providing there are adequate indexes and statistics are up to date. You never state that you're actually seeing a performance problem, or what the magnitude of any such problem is, or what your desired performance is.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have edited the question as per your suggestion I have given sample records like this we have multiple tables and coming plan it is secured environment I can't able paste the plan in SO

Comment: @pmbAustin I have done full scan on the server and stats are upto date ..we are querying on indexed columns only

Comment: It's very hard to do performance tuning without the query plan. Check if there are seeks or scans in your execution plan. If it's seeks, I don't thing there's a lot you can do.

Comment: We'd kind of need to see your indexes as well. Again, you haven't actually stated a problem. What is the problem you're seeing that you actually want help with?

Comment: Can you modify the structure of `@Large` without incurring the wrath of anyone? If so, adding a `HasValueOnSmallTable` column and then using an `UPDATE SET large.HasValueOnSmallTable = 1 FROM @Large large INNER JOIN @Small small ON large.INN = small.INN AND large.OUTT = small.OUTT` might speed things up. Probably need a clearing `UPDATE @Large SET HasValueOnSmallTable = 0` ahead of time.

Comment: In query level  i'm asking is there any more effective way to write while querying larger result set @pmbAustin

Comment: @Forty3 I didn't got your point at all

Comment: You're still not stating a problem. I don't see any problem. What PROBLEM are you having? Is it taking 5 hours to run? There's nothing wrong with your data or your update statement. SQL Server will "find the most effective way". That's what the query optimizer is for. If you're having an actual ISSUE, we'll need more information... like index definitions and a SQL Plan, to help you diagnose it. But I don'ts see any issues or problems here.

Comment: it is very big query which have multiple joins and it is taking more hours . Coming to stats and indexes are fine . Execution plan I can't share . I'm asking is there any specific steps we need to follow  when we are joining with Large result set

Comment: @mohan111 if you can't say what the problem is, you can't get an answer. No execution plan, no problem, no answer. 5M rows is *small data*. A 5M*20K join is nothing. This should take seconds. If it doesn't it means that either the indexes arent' suitable or the join columns aren't very selective. Appropriate indexes would be *only* those that *start* with the join columns.

Comment: @mohan111 for the query to take hours it means something is seriously wrong with the indexes if not the hardware itself. It may also mean that the query is not what you posted and instead of tables, there are complex views or subqueries that result in very complex and inefficient execution plans

Comment: And now a [msdn duplicate](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fe00cb52-ed63-40cd-b519-d0b59b179818/how-to-do-a-effective-join-when-querying-huge-table-with-small-table?forum=transactsql)

Comment: You are telling us: *it is very big query which have multiple joins and it is taking more hours*. This is not what you've shown. I'm absolutely sure, that your issue is not bound to this join. I'm pretty sure, that a RBAR-action is done on the whole lot **before filtering** this down to the needed smaller set. You might try to shift the small set to a temp table and proceed from there. You might try to use hints like [`FORCE ORDER`](http://www.sqlserver.info/syntax/force-order-query-hint/), but it is impossible to guide you with this little information.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to simply identify which records are shared between tables AND you can modify the `@Large` table, then consider keeping a flag on `@Large` updated with matches:

```
DECLARE @Large TABLE (INN BIGINT, OUTT BIGINT, HasMatch BIT DEFAULT(0))
INSERT INTO @Large (INN,OUTT)values (11356686,2101189)
INSERT INTO @Large (INN,OUTT)values (11369336,2101301)
INSERT INTO @Large (INN,OUTT)values (11358687,2101487)
INSERT INTO @Large (INN,OUTT)values (11369337,2101609)

DECLARE @small TABLE (INN BIGINT,OUTT BIGINT )
INSERT INTO @small (INN,OUTT)values (11356686,2101189)
INSERT INTO @small (INN,OUTT)values (11369337,2101609)

UPDATE @Large SET HasMatch = 0

UPDATE l
   SET l.HasMatch = 1
  FROM @Large l INNER JOIN @Small s ON l.INN = s.INN AND l.OUTT = s.OUTT

SELECT INN, OUTT, HasMatch FROM @Large
```

Again, this assumes you have some control over the table structure/data and can execute the `UPDATE` statements to populate the `HasMatch` column.

The upside - you get to take advantage of an `INNER JOIN` and all its inherent benefits (there are inherent benefits, right?).

Comment: Actually I have indicator column  to filter the records in Large table

Comment: @mohan111 that's not included in the question. Post the *actual* table schema and query, not a simplified version that may not have any relation to the problem. In any case a `BIT` column is useless. Its selectivity is so bad that including it in an index is meaningless - when half the entries are 1, it's cheaper to just scan the entire table than go through an index.